# SSAS Error The MyCube either does not exist or has not been processed when attempting to query through ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ssas

I have a cube, which has been processed, works from the BID environment, and I can run my MDX query in both SSEM, and the BID env.  I've created a role that contains the proper accounts/permissions, processed, and deployed the cube, *re-processed* it in SSEM, etc.  Now I'm trying to connect, and extract the data using ASP.NET 4.0, but I'm getting this error:

*The MyCube either does not exist or has not been processed*

Here's my code:

```
String connectionString = "Provider=MSOLAP.3; Data Source=myhost;Initial Catalog=myCatalog; User ID=myaccount; Password=myamazinglysecurepassword;";
String mdxSQL = " my MDX, which was taken directly from BID env. cube in design mode";
AdomdConnection connection = new AdomdConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
AdomdCommand cmd = new AdomdCommand(mdxSQL, connection);
CellSet cst = cmd.ExecuteCellSet();
...etc
```

Note: we are *not* using MSMDPUMP.dll to connect, we'd like to avoid that.

Any Ideas?

Comment: User id and password of the connect string are ignored by the Analysis Services driver if you do not use msmdpump. It always uses the user id of the Windows user executing the program. I think you can change the user ID using impersonation. But that has to be done in the code before connecting.

Comment: @FrankPl I'm getting the same thing using impersonation.

Comment: In the role that you created, did you put "everyone" in the selected users granted permission - just to eliminate that it is not a permissions problem?

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to consider.  How are users authenticating to your web app? What account is your application pool running as?

If you're using Integrated Windows in ASP.NET you may be getting a double-hop issue if IIS and SSAS on different servers. This would require you to set up Kerberos and trusted delegation SPN's between your application and the OLAP service.

See (SSAS and IIS):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn194199.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd632778.aspx

Otherwise there may be an issue with the account your application pool is running under.  I see in your connection string you have a specific account - so I presume you are trying to connect as one account rather than delegating user credentials to OLAP. The process running w3wp.exe is the identity which will attempt to connect to SSAS. If your application pool is not runnning as a domain account is may not be able to authenticate to SSAS.